# Good books on non-standard logics/set theories.

Tags: constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic, alternative-set-theories

So, I am looking for good books on intuicionistic logic & set theory theory and on constructive set theories. Does anyone has suggestions?

Background notes: I am familiar with work within ZFC, like proofs connected to L/diamond principles/trees; basic concepts of forcing and related to it consistency proofs; Godel's incompleteness theorems and very basics of model theory.

Comment: It would improve your Question to give some information about the level of text that you are prepared to read.   The references of [this short 1973 paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2272068) by H. Friedman might serve as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see :

- Anne Troelstra & Dirk van Dalen, [Constructivism in mathematics : An Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=-tc2qp0-2bsC&printsec=frontcover) (1988)

and :

- [Set Theory : Constructive and Intuitionistic $\mathsf {ZF}$](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/)  with many references to other SEP's entries and bibliography.

Also : John Bell, [Intuitionistic Set Theory](http://www.collegepublications.co.uk/logic/?00027) (2014).